# Internet pass-through to Android phone

Tags: internet, android, connection, share

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to share my computer's internet connection with my Android 2.2.1 through usb?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46604/is-there-a-way-to-share-my-computers-internet-connection-with-my-android-2-2-1-t)

Is there any way to use the "Internet pass-through" feature on Ubuntu? So far I've only seen it working under Windows with the HTC Share tool.

Shouldn't there be something similar for Ubuntu? I'm using Natty Narwhal...

Thanks in advance for any replies =)