# How can I share my Internet connection through USB?

Tags: android, squid

Is there a way to share an Internet connection from PC (wlan0 interface) with an Android Phone connected through USB (usb0 interface with usb-tethering)?
I guess it's possible with squid, but I don't know anything about squid.
I'm using froyo & Ubuntu 11.04 so please guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to share my computer's Internet connection with my Android through USB?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46604/is-there-a-way-to-share-my-computers-internet-connection-with-my-android-throug)

Answer (score -1):

Can your phone tether with you Android? If so, you can access the wi-fi from your phone. It should be in the settings, networking/wireless.