# Share internet from PC to unrooted android smart phone connected via USB cable

Tags: networking, usb, internet, android, ethernet

I am running **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** with **Windows 7** Dual boot (both 32 bit) in my desktop. I use **cable broadband (Ethernet)**. I have an **unrooted** android smart phone running **KitKat 4.4.2**. This device has a feature called **Usb Internet** (Description below) which allows me to share my computer's Internet in **Windows** by enabling **ICS**.

> **Usb Internet**
>
> Sharing Windows PC Internet via USB cable

This is procedure by which ICS is achieved between Windows and android phone:

1. Connect phone to PC via usb cable.
2. Select Usb Internet from phone settings.
3. Select OS version to *Windows 7*.
4. Select 'Done'.

[Steps 5 to 8 is taken from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7)]

5. In PC, open Network Connections by clicking the Start button and then clicking Control Panel.
6. In the search box, type adapter, and then, under *Network and Sharing Center*, click *View network connections*.
7. Right-click the connection that you want to share, and then click Properties. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
8. Click the Sharing tab, and then select the *Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection* check box.

And after that I am able to access Internet from the phone.

But in *step 3*, I see no option for *Ubuntu* (only Windows). So in Ubuntu, I select in that step *Windows 7* and Continue. Then a new connection appears in *Network Manager* but I cannot share my existing Ethernet connection with this new one. It is because my Ethernet network requires *Address*, *Netmask*, *Gateway*, *DNS Servers* which I have to input by changing *IPv4 Settings*, *Method* to *Manual* (So I cannot select *Shared to other Computers*).

Can anyone please help me solve this issue? Only condition is phone will not be rooted.

Comment: If you landed on this page, and your phone is already rooted: http://askubuntu.com/questions/46604/is-there-a-way-to-share-my-computers-internet-connection-with-my-android-throug

Comment: Check out: http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/networking/guide-connect-android-to-linux-pc-t2825476 (didn't try the traffic forwarding yet, but the USB Internet set-up worked flawlessly; for which I've been trying and searching in vain for several months) and also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14256/how-do-you-set-up-internet-pass-through-reverse-tether-on-linux (with some nice tips for HTC users)

Comment: If you landed here, and still don't want to root your device: Try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free