# How to share my desktop's Internet connection with my Android through USB cable?

Tags: usb, android, tethering

Android version - 5.1
Ubuntu 14.04 , 32bit
When I turn on USB tethering,I get a notification saying "connected". And a new connection setup shows up automatically . [network setups screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36MRL.png)

But I cant browse web from my android device .

Comment: Wrong way around, the phone shares its connection to the pc that way. You see that `hotspot`  entry in your screenshot? That will broadcast the PC wifi as a hotspot, if your wireless chip supports it.

Comment: No, I added the hotspot setup menually, that hotspot does not have any relation with USB tethering. However, the " wired connection 2" showed up automatically, after I  turned on USB tethering from my mobile. @MarkKirby

Comment: You have it the wrong way round, when you turn usb tether on, on the phone it shares the phones connection to the pc, not the pc to the phone.

Comment: So, what should I do ? @MarkKirby

Comment: Create a hotspot https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html on the pc and then connect the phone using wifi.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to share my internet via wifi, I need to know how can I share internet via USB cable .@MarkKirby

Comment: I could only find this http://askubuntu.com/questions/46604/is-there-a-way-to-share-my-computers-internet-connection-with-my-android-throug on here, it is old so IDK if it is still relevant and this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb has more.

Comment: New answer that should do what you want https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266046/how-to-enable-internet-sharing-via-usb-ubuntu-20-04-to-android-6-0-1-and-10/1357792